# How to create a 5-color linear gradient border using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css, gradient

How can I make this 5 color linear gradient border just like this image? also the below line?

[image]

I have tried with this code.

`bg-gradient-to-r from-[#83C59B] via-[#FCF09A] to-[#71CAEE]`

but can't set 5 colors.

Now I want a 5 color linear gradient border using Tailwind CSS.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `bg-gradient-to-r` is setting background-image, not border-image, so it won't work for your need anyway. I don't think there are pre-defined Tailwind classes for border-image.

You have to either define your own custom theme/plugin or use [**Arbitrary properties**](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties).

For example, this arbitrary property:

```html
<div class='[border-image:linear-gradient(to_right,#83C59B,#FCF09A,red,purple,#71CAEE)_1]'> </div>
```

is equivalant to:

```css
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #83C59B, #FCF09A, red, purple, #71CAEE) 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="border-gradient p-3 text-white bg-black">Press</button>
```

works for me when I tried. (Adjust the colors for your image). The style part is

```
<style>
  .border-gradient {
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #83C59B, #FCF09A, #71CAEE, #111111, #880088) 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you're using arbitrary values you can pass as many colors as you wish to any of `from`, `via` or `to`. Keep `bg-gradient-to-r` to specify direction. So any of these are valid:

```html
from-[#83C59B] // one color
from-[#83C59B,red,green] // multiple
via-[#FCF09A,red,green,blue,magenta,gray,pink,violet] // a lot of colors
to-[#83C59B,red]
```

If you do not specify `from` or `to` it will be defaulted to `transparent`. `via` is optional one

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/EApdRWTges)